# Need Help Accessing Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

So I'm horrible with Arrays and I'm trying to access the following array:

```
Array ( 
                    [Response] => Array (
                        [Status] => OK 
                        [Request] => street_address
                     )
                    [Geometry] => Array ( 
                        [Latitude] => 37.564096 
                        [Longitude] => -97.2657311
                 ) 
      )
```

My goal is to set Longitude and Latitude to their own variables so that I can reuse them how I wish.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And your code so far?

Comment: @user741166 You can check out my post for an indepth explanation on multi dimensional arrays. Hopefully I have made it clear enough for you to grasp straight away. any problems in understanding just give me a shout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IN SHORT**

Like this

```
$latitude = $myArray['Geometry']['Latitude'];
$longitude = $myArray['Geometry']['Longitude'];
```

**DETAILED EXPLANATION****

This is what your array should look like in php as your current array would create errors.

```
$myArray = Array ( 
    "Response" => 
        Array ( 
            "Status" => OK, 
            "Request" => street_address 
        ),
    "Geometry" => 
        Array ( 
          "Latitude" => 37.564096,
          "Longitude" => -97.2657311 
    ) 
);
```

As you can see you have two tiers of arrays, an array within an array.
In the outer array you have two elements addressed by their following keys:

- `Response`, and
- `Geometry`

Each of these keys contains another array with 2 elements
To access the first array you would write down the array and their key name:

`$myArray['Response'];` would contain the inner array:

```
Array ( 
    "Status" => OK, 
    "Request" => street_address 
)
```

and `myArray['Geometry'];` would contain the other inner array

```
Array ( 
      "Latitude" => 37.564096,
      "Longitude" => -97.2657311 
)
```

To access the inner most array in one go you would do the following for each element youre trying to access

```
echo "Latitude is " . $myArray['Geometry']['Latitude'];
echo "Longitude is " . $myArray['Geometry']['Longitude'];?>
```

you're basically saying, go into myArray to the `Geometry` key where you'll find another array where i'd like you to access the `Latitude` key and bring back what is inside that.

same goes for accessing the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can access by -

```
$yourarray = /*PUT YOUR ARRAY HERE*/

echo "Latitude is ".$yourarray['Geometry']['Latitude'];
echo "Longitude is ".$yourarray['Geometry']['Longitude'];
```

Comment: @Pavan - It should have the original array code, not the output. I just corrected it.